# Constructor error with given type, cannot be applied

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, dijkstra

I'm using Dijkstras Algorithm and I can't seem to figure out why my constructor isn't working correctly with what I'm trying to do.

Specifically this line: A.edges = new Edge[]{ new Edge(B, 35), new Edge(C, 50)};

Gives me the error: "error: constructor Edge in class Edge cannot be applied to given types;"

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    //sets all the cities/nodes to a vertex
    Vertex A = new Vertex("CityA");
    Vertex B = new Vertex("CityB");

    //distance from each city to their new cities
    A.edges = new Edge[]{ new Edge(B, 35), new Edge(C, 50)};

}

public static void dijkstra(Vertex s){
    s.shortestDist = 0;
    PriorityQueue<Vertex> cityQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
    cityQueue.add(s);

    while(!cityQueue.isEmpty()){
        Vertex w = cityQueue.poll();
        for (Edge x : w.edges){
            Vertex v = x.city;
            int price = x.price;
            int priceOfTrip = w.shortestDist + price;
            if(priceOfTrip < v.shortestDist){   //relaxes the edge that it's on
                cityQueue.remove(v);
                v.shortestDist = priceOfTrip;
                v.prev = w;
                cityQueue.add(v);
            }
        }
    }

}

//Contructor
public static class Edge{
    public static int price;
    public static Vertex city;
    public static void Edge(Vertex altCity, int altPrice){
        city = altCity;
        price = altPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest, instead of writing code directly, read basis first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
public static void Edge(Vertex altCity, int altPrice){
```

is not a constructor; it's a static method that returns `void`.  Constructors aren't `static` and they don't return anything.  Try

```
public Edge(Vertex altCity, int altPrice){
```

In addition, your `Edge` class's member variables shouldn't be `static` either:

```
public int price;
public Vertex city;
```

Comment: Oh thanks, that makes sense. Constructors are also suppose to be outside of the main class file right? so after the last closing bracket of the public class ExampleFile{?

Comment: No, any constructors are always part of the class definition and must be part of the class body.  The location of your `Edge` constructor within your source code was correct, but the syntax was incorrect enough for it to be interpreted as a method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a method syntax :

```
public static void Edge(Vertex altCity, int altPrice){
```

This is not a constructor. Your constructor should be like :

```
public Edge(Vertex altCity, int altPrice){
```

You can [refer here for learning.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Further, your fields are class variables, so every time you call constructor same variables will be set with new values for all objects, not sure if this is what you want.